# Update MacbookAIR Firmware without original hard disk

Tags: macbook-pro, bootable-disk, efi

I got original SSD broken.
My MacbookAir 7.1 got only YOSEMITE Internet Recovery.
Now, I've bought a SAMSUNG 970 NVME M.2 disk and the system could recognize it using NVME kext patched but cannot boot because my MacbookAir was never updated with HighSierra (and so, no BootROM upgrade is done.With High SIERRA NVME disks become bootable)

Do you think this tool could help me? http://forum.netkas.org/index.php/topic,852.0.html

Other way to follow?

No way to boot the disk using CLOVER or reFIND for the moment. (am I missing something?)

The only thing I've done is reinstalling YOSEMITE successfully directly to external drive using Internet Recovery, but when trying to update to HighSierra or Mojave the NVME disk and the external one are both unselectable due to "missing firmware"

Comment: if it is Firmware you are looking for yo can find it here https://support.apple.com/downloads/macnotebooks

Comment: Try upgrading to Sierra first, not High Sierra

Comment: This Is not a duplicate...The firmware download Is not available in apple link...I said MacBook Air 7.1 and in the Site the firmwares cover tipo the 6.2(higher versione foto firmware upgrade while installing new osx release)

Comment: The Sierra Will not solve my issue because NVME support arrives in High Sierra...but the main problem Is that ti upgrade fronte Yosemite ti High Sierra internal hdd ESP Is needed otherwise It fails...It seems..